How to put a screen on a foundation vent that has pipes passing through it
I have a foundation vent (6" x 16") that has pipes coming through it. Is there a straightforward way to put a screen over this vent?
The previous owner had it blocked with fiberglass insulation, but as I understand it, vents like this one need to be kept open and allow air to flow, ideally with 1/8" metal mesh screens to keep out mice.
I bought a roll of the mesh and tried to snip it to fit, and make holes for the pipes, but this turned out to be much more difficult than it looked. When I put the screen in place, no matter how carefully I cut it, it would always get misshaped and leave gaps at the top and bottom, defeating the purpose.
Is there some contractor trick to this? Would it be okay just to stuff a bunch of steel wool into the gaps and call it good?



Using steel pipes of a similar diameter to the pipes will make a hole saw/hole punch if hammered with the mesh between the pipe and a solid piece of concrete/steel. Then one or two straight cuts to slip over the pipes. Measure twice to make sure the holes line up.

It's not clear whether your question is to cover the ends of the pipes, or the penetration in the foundation wall.  But if the latter, yes stuffing some stainless steel wool (or those stainless steel kitchen scrubbers) in the gaps would work fine.
